# Finding correct xpath for the "Next" button on Google search

Tags: css, r, xpath

I'm using R, but I can't seem to extract the correct `xpath` for the "Next"
button on Google search's. Eg, one searches something, scrolls to the bottom, and then clicks the "Next" to the right of the list of numbers.

This is what I can extract from Chrome's "inspect":

```
//*[@id="pnnext"]
```

But when I get a blank list when I try using that `xpath`. The CSS Selector gadget gives me this:

```
//*+[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "ch", " " ))]//span
```

But same problem. To be useful in R code, or "clickable," I know it has be from the `href` part. What's the correct `xpath` to "click" the "Next" button?

---

Code leading up:

```
library(RSelenium) # run in docker

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://books.google.com/")
books <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "[name = 'q']")
books$sendKeysToElement(list("NHL books", key = "enter"))

# Clicks on all 10 links of first result page
bookElem <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath",
                       "//h3[@class = 'LC20lb']//parent::a")
links <- sapply(bookElem, function(bookElem){
  bookElem$getElementAttribute("href")
})

# Gets stuff I want from every search result
big_list <- lapply(links, function(link) {

  # Navigate to each link
  remDr$navigate(link)

  # Do various things
  if (...) {
  ...
  } else {
  ...
  }

})
```

Comment: How are you doing the searching? Are you using Selenium to enter a search keyword?

Comment: Searching something in google, hitting enter, and wanting to hit next after that

Comment: But in order to scrape results, how are you getting to a search? What's your code leading up to the point of trying to hit a "next" button? Or are you searching in your browser and then trying to scrape based on that URL, such as this mess when I search "web scraping" in Firefox: https://www.google.com/search?ei=Jiu2XIH1JoXz5gL3gJmIBw&q=web+scraping&oq=web+scraping&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.12169.13926..14246...0.0..0.105.826.11j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i131j0i131i67.j0oSagYuruo

Comment: Asking because I just finished up a project that required searching a page and scraping, which I did with RSelenium to find the search box by its selector, enter text, press enter, then scrape, using a Firefox debug driver

Comment: Added it. Search a phrase, hit enter, scrape some stuff from every link on the page, and then click "next" to do the same on every page thereafter. If this is a stupid method, let me know! (Actually, though). I essentially have no idea where to place the "next" elements within the script, but I do know now that the `//*[@id="pnnext"]` will work to hit next, just not within the actual scraping code

Comment: I think I'm trying to do something similar to what you were doing in your project, just with chrome & RSelenium running through docker (such fun, right?)

Comment: What's the code used to get the next button? getting it by id works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you asked for an XPath solution, i will add that.

This works for me:

```
nextButton <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "//*[@id = 'pnnext']")
```

So actually your xpath does not look wrong. Maybe there is an error when wrapping it in the `findElement()` function.

I will add you the full code so that you can reproduce the results.

**Full example:**

```
remDr$navigate("https://books.google.com/")
books <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "[name = 'q']")
books$sendKeysToElement(list("NHL books", key = "enter"))

bookElem <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath",
                               "//h3[@class = 'LC20lb']//parent::a")
links <- sapply(bookElem, function(bookElem){
  bookElem$getElementAttribute("href")
})


nextButton <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "//*[@id = 'pnnext']")
nextButton$clickElement()

remDr$screenshot(TRUE)
```

[image]

```
remDr$getCurrentUrl()

"https://www.google.com/searchq=NHL+books&tbm=bks&ei=M9y2XL2HBPDjkgWklqXoDg&start=10&
sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwj97OjL09bhAhXwsaQKHSRLCe0Q8NMDCIUB&biw=1020&bih=694&dpr=1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to find the element by id?

```r
remDr$findElement(using = "id", "pnnext")
```

I find it always more secure to find elements by a unique value when possible.